# Jekyll - Liquid Templating - Exclude a Category from Widget

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am attempting to rebuild a sidebar widget which shows my categories used in Jekyll. It works fine as it is now. I want to change the liquid templating to exclude one specific category link from being shown in this widget.

```
{% assign cat_list = site.categories %}
  {% if cat_list.first[0] == null %}
    {% for category in cat_list %}
      <li><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/categories#{{ category }}">{{ category }} <span class="cat-count">{{ cat_list[category].size }}</span></a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
    {% for category in cat_list %}
      <li><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/categories#{{ category[0] }}">{{ category[0] }} <span class="cat-count">{{ category[1].size }}</span></a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% assign cat_list = nil %}
```

I think what I want is something like

```
{% for category in cat_list **UNLESS category = 'CATEGORY'** %}
```

But that did not work. I'm kinda stuck, is this possible?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Not displayed categories array :

`{% assign noDisplay = "one,two,three" | split: "," %}` => ["one", "two", "three"]

The test :

```
{% unless noDisplay contains category[0] %}
{{ category[0] }}...
{% endunless %}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am way too new at liquid / programming in general to totally understand how I would implement this in my current code. But I'll take a stab now and return when I do figure out what worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @David Jacquel

```
{% assign noDisplay = "CATEGORY" | split: "," %}
{% assign cat_list = site.categories %}
  {% if cat_list.first[0] == null %}
    {% for category in cat_list %}
      <li><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/categories#{{ category }}">{{ category }} <span class="cat-count">{{ cat_list[category].size }}</span></a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
    {% for category in cat_list %}
    {% unless noDisplay contains category[0] %}
      <li><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/categories#{{ category[0] }}">{{ category[0] }} <span class="cat-count">{{ category[1].size }}</span></a></li>
      {% endunless %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% assign cat_list = nil %}
```